# Sometimes, the window title bar is missing [Linux / gnome]

Tags: front-end, linux

Sometimes, but not always, when I open a mathematica notebook, the window titlebar (the one on top of your application window, where you can close and maximise a window) is missing. In this situation, also the taskbar does not show up. The taskbar shows up on other screens, where I have other applications open. If I have two mathematica windows open on two different screens, the taskabr is nowhere. When I open another application on one of the screens, the taskbar shows up on this screen and the application has the usual window titlebar.

If I close the mathematica notebook and reopen it, titlebar and taskbar are both still missing. When I launch the application mathematica itself, instead of opening a notebook directly, I get everything back. Taks and titlebar are only missing when opening a notebook directly.

Is there somewhere an appearance setting I am missing that could cause this strange behaviour?

I am using manjaro, GNOME 3.38.2 and X11.

Comment: You might want to contact Wolfram support about this. Indicate your precise version of Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought about that as well. I reported my issue to the support. Let's see. :)

Comment: I also have this issue on Fedora 32 and Gnome 3.36 (X11-session) with some notebooks. What helps is to open a context menu in a notebook, select "Toggle Full Screen" and then repeat the same action. After that the title bar usually reappears. I admit that I was too lazy to report this to the WRI, so it's great that you did it.

Comment: Are you using any Gnome shell extensions? It is possible some extensions might be buggy and interfering with the normal operation.

Comment: Good point, @Sâu! The Wolfram support reported that they look into this and might fix it in a future release (I already got an announcement that I'll soon get the 12.2 download link, but I doubt that this already includes any fix on that matter, that would be insanely fast. .P) Meanwhile, I just keep hitting F12 twice, to get rid of it, as suggested by @vsht.

Answer (score 1):

The Wolfram support got back to me with a solution: A "[Manual Clean Start](https://support.wolfram.com/12464)".

1. I saved my mathematica key somewhere easily accessible. (You find it under Help -> About...)
2. Close mathematica
3. Delete / rename (to have a backup just in case something happens)
   the `UserBaseDirectory` and the `BaseDirectory`:

- ~/.Mathematica
- ~/.Wolfram
- ~/.cache/Wolfram
- /usr/share/Mathematica

4. Launch mathematica and re-active it with your key.